# Meaning of $\nabla r^2=2r$

Tags: calculus, vectors

If $\vec r$ denotes the  separation vector between a fixed point $(a,b,c)$ and a variable point $(x,y,z)$, and $r$ its length, then $\nabla r^2=2\vec r$.

I can prove this mathematically:

$$r^2=(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2$$
$$\nabla r^2=2(x-a)\hat i+2(y-b)\hat j+2(z-c)\hat k=2\vec{r}$$

But what does this mean geometrically?

Gradient always points along the direction of slope of a function. Here, the gradient should point along the separation vector itself. But why does its magnitude double?

Comment: Define "practically."

Comment: Consider the 1d case. If you are okay with the derivative of x^2 being 2x, this is analogous.

Comment: So gradient is simply the slope of a curve? (I just started learning it from Griffith's electrodynamics book)

Comment: you have to specify your coordinates system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geometrically this is a bit challenging because you are likely envisioning a "directed line" from one point to another. However, the quantity you are modelling is the vector of squared differences (whose dot product with $\mathbf{1}$ give you the squared Euclidean norm between the two points). The components of this vector are nonlinear in the separation, so the rate at which this vector changes is a function of the separation.

Geometrically, you can picture $r^2$ as a function:

$$r^2((a,b,c),(x,y,z)) = (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2 $$

This is just a 4-d parabolic "bowl" with $(a,b,c)$ as the bottom of the bowl. The gradient just tells you which direction in 3 dimensions takes you up the bowl the fastest.